# How to add self-signed certificates to different browsers?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssl

How can I add self-signed certificates to e.g: Google Chrome under Linux (from the command line)? Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to use the [`certutil`](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/certutil.html) utility to do this (it's included in Debian/Ubuntu's `libnss3-tools` package and should be in a similar package in other distros). Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work on either Chrome or Firefox's NSS databases on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [LinuxCertManagement](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_cert_management.md):

> For example, to trust a root CA certificate for issuing SSL server certificates, use
>
> `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n <nickname> -i <filename>`
>
> Note: to trust a self-signed server certificate, we should use
>
> `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n <nickname> -i <filename>`
>
> Unfortunately that doesn't work because of [NSS bug 531160](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=531160). To work around the NSS bug, you have to trust it as a CA using the "C,," trust flags.

For Firefox, change the `-d` argument to Firefox profile path, without `sql:`.

Comment: So because of the bug it's really insecure to "C,," a self-signed certificate on XY website?

Comment: @LanceBaynes: All X.509 certificates have a "basic constraints" extension. Even if you mark the certificate as a "trusted CA" in NSS, it still needs to have "CA: true" in the basic constraints extension in order to be accepted as an authority. But unfortunately many self-signed certificates *do* have this set, so giving the 'C' flag is indeed insecure.